# How to select attribute value for a selected element with wombat

Tags: ruby, rubygems, css-selectors

I want to select href value of a link that I have selected with wombat:

this is how to the selector looks like:

```
parent_url "css=#breadcrumbcontainer > div > p a:last-child"
```

wombat has property formats like: html, text etc. Even if I do html on this selection, I get the inner text of the link, which is not useful to me.

Please suggest a css selector that would just return href or a way to get href using some property format option of wombat.

Source code of wombat gem can be found at: https://github.com/felipecsl/wombat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t use CSS to select an attribute, you can only select elements. You will need to use XPath to get the `href`. Try using:

```
parent_url "xpath=//*[@id = 'breadcrumbcontainer']/div/p//*[position() = last() and self::a]/@href"
```

I got this XPath using `Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for("your css query")` and adding `/@href` to select the attribute node. Wombat is using Nokogiri, so this kind of translation is what is happening already.

Comment: Hey Matt,

I figured out this solution myself too. This is what I am using:
parent_url xpath: "(//*[@id='breadcrumbcontainer']/div//a)[last()]/@href"

Though your answer is quite close, not sure if it is better or not, I am accepting it as the right answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @whizcreed Since I don’t know the structure of the target web page I can only give the XPath produced by Nokogiri when it transforms your CSS. Since you know the page structure you can create a more succinct XPath expression. They certainly look similar.